# VNC/Steam game Streaming service with a Windows server with no monitor plugged in is only 640x480 resolution

Tags: windows-7, resolution, streaming, vnc, steam

VNC, Steam Streaming, and Windows 7 desktop only seem to support 640x480 resolution when there is no monitor plugged in.

Is there an application that can "spoof" a monitor being plugged in? I'd like to leave my server in the closet without a monitor. I have a 4k laptop and it'd be awesome to stream games in 4k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply rebooting the server after having unplugged the monitor fixed it for me. Windows 7 detected there was no monitor, and did the right thing (nVidia GPU).